# match first columns in two files

Tags: perl

I have two files of unequal sizes. First file has two columns and second has only one column. I want to match the column in second file to the first column in first file and if they match, print the whole line from the first file. Pretty simple but I am stuck. Here's what I did after opening and storing the contents of both the files in arrays

```
foreach(@q) #second file
{
        $line=$_;
        foreach(@gs) #first file
        {
           $line1=$_;
           if ( $line1=~ /$line/ )
           {
             print $line1;
           }

        }
}
```

This doesnt give an output.

Comment: Turn the second file into a hash, then test each line in the first file against the hash.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you might be getting tripped up by line endings for one or both of your files.  Regardless, it's not necessary to slurp both your files, just the 2nd one.  And a regex is most likely overkill, a simple equality check is sufficient, and more likely what you intend.

The following is probably what you intend:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file1 = 'foo.txt';
my $file2 = 'bar.txt';

open my $fh2, '<', $file2;
my @keys = <$fh2>;
chomp(@keys);

open my $fh1, '<', $file1;

while (my $line = <$fh1>) {
    my $fields = split ' ', $line;

    if (grep {$fields[0] eq $_} @keys) {
        print $line;
    }
}
```

Comment: If there are a lot of keys from file2, it would be better to put them into a hash: `my %keyhash; @keyhash{@keys} = undef;`  Then instead of doing the grep, you do `print $line if exists $keyhash{$fields[0]};`

Comment: Agreed, regardless of the list length.  However, was tailoring the advice to the beginner that would choose to do 2 for loops.  If loops is all he knows at the moment, at least he could do them more semantically using a `grep` ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file2 = 'foo.txt';
my $file1 = 'bar.txt';
my @line1;
open FF,$file2;
    while(<FF>)
    {
        unshift(@line1,$_); 
    }
close(FF);
open FH,$file1;
    while(<FH>)
    {
        my $se=$_;
        chomp($se);
        foreach my $data (@line1)
        {
            if($data=~m/^\s*$se\s*\t/is)
            {
                print $data."\n";
            }   
        }
    }
close(FH);
```

Try This....

Comment: This doesnt return anything